# How to get Order Time in Magento?

Tags: date, pdf, time, magento-1.7, invoice

I am trying to rewrite my PDF invoices in Magento. How can i display the created time without the date of a Order?

I am preparing the class insertOrder() in /app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php.

```
$page->drawText(Mage::helper('core')->formatDate($order->getCreatedAtStoreDate(), 'short', false), 100, 100, 'UTF-8');
```

shows only the time in combination with date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to display the time part only would be this:

```
$sTime = Mage::app()
    ->getLocale()
    ->date(strtotime($order->getCreatedAtStoreDate()), null, null, false)
    ->toString('H:m:s');

$page->drawText($sTime, 100, 100, 'UTF-8');
```

Magento's locale uses a modified `Zend_Date` class for date/time operations.

See the `toString()` method of `app/code/core/Zend/Date.php` for parameter infos.